# When feeds post an instant deleted question in chat the formatting is off

Tags: bug, design, chat, feed

In the [SEDE Chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede) I have two feeds, one is the Twitter StackStatus, the other is a networkwide filter on questions tagged [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer).

Today I noticed these [feed items](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7702344#7702344):

[image]

The second item clearly has a different layout (["blog layout"](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7704361#7704361)) while all items in that screenshot are from the same feed and are posted by the [feeds user](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-2/feeds). The only difference here is that all other questions fetched by that feed existed for a longer period while the question in question [only existed for 1 minute and 28 seconds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327800/draw-state-diagrams-and-make-predictions) before it was deleted again by its owner.

While I could argue it is a nice feature to see instantly the question is deleted I still feel this is a kind of bug / race condition.

Was this a temporary glitch or is there a root cause that can be fixed? If so, would you mind putting it on your 6 to 8 weeks schedule.

Comment: That happens with other feeds (I've seen [Marvin](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-638/marvin) have that weird formatting)

Comment: @Stormblessed do you happen to have an example. I've looked through a couple of pages and find none, so it certainly isn't often.

Comment: It hasn't happened in a while in [The Restaurant at the End of the Universe](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe) that I've noticed, but it looks about the same as your screenshot when this happens.

Answer (score 2):

There is a brief [discussion in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7704356#7704356) about this but, what happens when a post is quoted, as described in the section of the FAQ titled "[How do I format my messages](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#formatting)", is that certain types of posts are oneboxed.

The square box with a number in it is the number of upvotes that the post has received, in the case of a deleted post it's NULL, while those with zero votes are shown as zero. Note Glorfindel's is shown as 5 but currently he has 15, the amount isn't *live* and gets grabbed when the Feed runs.

Comment: Yeah. I realize that the one-box is created when the feed runs and that it isn't live. It doesn't look like [score is null, ever](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1043081) but the post being deleted plays certainly a role here.

Comment: I can't argue SQL with you, with what little I know (have time to lookup/figure out) if I [change "Score" to "ViewCount"](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/edit/1043086) I can find plenty, so perhaps SE's code compares a different field. The 'Score box' is what is being removed.